# Сброс перевода при обновлении английской строки

Tags: предложение, локализация

Собственно уже не первый раз возникает ситуация, когда по причине изменения исходного (английского) варианта текста, слетает перевод на русской части stack overflow. В связи с этим есть два, дополняющих друг друга, предложения к разработчикам сайта:

1. Обеспечить возможность сохранения старой версии перевода до утверждения новой.
2. Выделять особенным образом сообщения локализационного бота в чате для строк, которые были именно изменены, а не добавлены в первый раз. Или как-то иначе дополнительно уведомлять участников, задействованных в переводе сайта на русский.

Выполнение этих действий позволит держать локализованную версию SO (не только на русском) в более согласованном виде и оперативнее реагировать на возможные изменения переводов уже используемой функциональности.

Answer (score 2):

Отличное предложение! Только в текущей архитектуре реализовать не получится. Проблема в том, что для ассоциации версий на разных языках используется ключ, который представлен в виде хэш строки. Обновляется строка, обновляется хэш. При появлении новой строки (обновлении старой), строке будет присвоен новый хэш, затем обновляется база строк на Transifex. В этот момент все старые строки, которых больше нет в проекте, пропадут. У нас нет «памяти хэшей».

Comment: Но можно ведь и для английского включить перевод, а базовую версию сделать какой-то особой и неизменной?

Comment: @Qwertiy Уверен, вариантов может быть много, но они все требуют изменения архитектуры системы локализации.

Comment: Я как раз предложил вариант без изменения архитектуры.

Comment: @Qwertiy В последний раз, когда я смотрел на реализацию, английская строка являлась, по сути, ключом (на самом деле нет, но от строки берется хэш, который и есть ключ). Английские строки правятся напрямую в коде. Правка английских строк на Transifex может вызвать неразбериху. Чтобы все было «в одном месте» необходим с первого дня оперировать константами. Чего, опять же, как мне кажется, не будет даже в новых продуктах, таких как Документация, так как это сильно снизит скорость и удобство разработки.

Comment: _"Правка английских строк на Transifex может вызвать неразбериху."_ - в принципе, да, может. Но это почти бесплатный вариант в плане затраченного на реализацию времени. В коде строка как бы замораживается, а если что-то надо поменять, то это меняется в английской локализации. Для такого надо просто включить локализацию на англоязычных сайтах.